# Is there an alternative way of displaying an image depends on my input?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to show the level of connectivity of the wifi depends on my input. I used custom wifi image in sfsymbol. The code result is not really good, so I am looking for a better way. Sorry about this if it's something that not possible in Xcode.
//please look my image atttachment[image: imageimage]
import SwiftUI

```
     class ViewMode: ObservableObject {
@Published var rece = ""
  }

struct MyApp: View {

@State private var passConnection: String = ""

var body: some View {
    MyConnectionView(incomingConnection: $passConnection)
}
 }

struct MyConnectionView: View {

@Binding var incomingConnection: String

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            if incomingConnection == "low" {
                CustomWifi1
            }
            else if incomingConnection == "medium" {
                CustomWifi2
            }
            else {
                CustomWifi3
            }
        }
    }
}

var CustomWifi1: some View {
    Image("custom1")
}
var CustomWifi2: some View {
    Image("custom2")
}
var CustomWifi3: some View {
    Image("custom3")
}
var CustomWifi4: some View {
    Image("custom4")
}
var CustomWifi5: some View {
    Image("custom5")
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display a different level of connection with SwiftUI and the feature of SF Symbols by using "variableValue" modifier of the "Image".
Therefore, you don't have to create multiple customized wifi images for your app. Also, you should have included #swiftui tag in your question.

Try this code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
@State var connectionValue = 0.0
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Slider(value: $connectionValue)
        Image(systemName: "wifi", variableValue: connectionValue)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much just what im looking for. can this work with other images?

Comment: This feature works with only specific images in SF Symbols. Open SF Symbols>Variable, then you will find the images that work with this feature.